# Missing tag badge

Tags: support, tag-badges

If you check the tag page for [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2), you'll notice that I'm the top answerer for this tag.

However, despite having 129 upvotes across 20 non-community wiki answers (it was 134 across 21, but I deleted my own question and its answer because it was too localized) for it, I'm missing the 100 upvote bronze badge for this tag.

What's the deal?

Comment: I'm in a similar place for "Minecraft", although I have the one for "Starcraft-2".  I have no idea what the real requirements are, but they differ somehow from what's written in the badge description.

Comment: @Strix You only have 18 answers in Minecraft, which the badge notes you need at least 20.

Comment: Ever wonder why I don't have the golden tag badge for Starcraft-2?

Comment: @tzenes 4 more answers and you'll be there. Though at this stage you do already have 2k score in StarCraft 2...

Comment: @Grace I thought I needed 200 answers in the tag? I'm at 188, which would mean 12 more...

Comment: @tzenes You do, but I was going by the x196 on your stats rather than the "188 answered" in the tooltip, whoops. It is indeed 12.

Comment: @Grace its those darn CW.  If people weren't so CW crazy I'd have a boat load more stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a minimum of 100 total questions with the tag necessary to award the badge. There are only 99 questions with [team-fortress-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2).

Quoting the badges page in the top right, switching the emphasis to my own:

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions  with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in **a tag with 100+ total questions**, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

Comment: There were 100 prior to me deleting the one mentioned in the original post.  No idea how that question didn't get closed as too localized, seeing as how it was applicable for exactly 2 hours.  I deleted it *after* making this meta topic.

Comment: @Powerlord Well, tag badges actually can get revoked if the badge requirements cease to be met. Best thing to do is just hope for a new TF2 question. Or pester badp to ask a new one. Also take into account that tag badges do *not* get awarded immediately upon satisfying the necessary requirements - they probably are part of a daily process like the Epic badge and other "Not happening all that often" badges.

Comment: @Powerlord Looks like you [earned this badge on Sunday](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/badges/210/team-fortress-2), shortly after we got our hundredth TF2 question (from badp, even).